# d3 localStorage compare arrays .filter coffee script; array variable not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, coffeescript, global-variables

I am setting the CSS of a div conditionally. For this I use a .filter. The filter compares 2 arrays.
When I run the code below, it does not work. When I hardcode the array_1 content (taken from console; uncomment in code shown), then it does work.

I assume that the array resulting from the loop is not ready for the filter function in time ?

```
  labelEnter.append("div")
  .attr("class", "bubble-label-name")
  .text((d) -> textValue(d))


  arraylocal = []
  typeofKey = null
  for key of localStorage
    typeofKey = (typeof localStorage[key])
    array = arraylocal.push key
    break
  console.log(array)

 # array = ["show", "cum", "nec", "show"]

  console.log(d3.selectAll(".bubble-label-name").filter((d) -> textValue(d) in array).style("border", "1px solid red"))
```

Why does the use of the hard coded array content work, but when I use the array variable, it does not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your reply. The following code works. I will review the link that you posted. Thank you.

```
 arraylocal = []
  for key of localStorage
    arraylocal.push key


d3.selectAll(".bubble-label-name").filter((d) -> textValue(d) in arraylocal).style("border", "1px solid red")
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be expecting `arrayLocal.push(key)` to return a copy of the array.  However, the [`push()` method returns a the new length of the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), and this is all that will be stored in your `array` variable.